# SQL refer to foreign keys with a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I have to check a few foreign keys in a loop and need to replace the name of the foreign key field with a variable (@fk_field for example).

My query looks like this:

```
    SELECT 
        ad.id 
        , ad.@fk_field
        , a1.@jnktn_field
    FROM @tblname tbl LEFT JOIN @jnktn_tbl jnktn ON tbl.@fk_field=jnktn.@jnktn_field
    WHERE ad.FK1 <> isnull(a1.ID,0)
```

Apparently it's not possible to use a variable directly after a point like I did, but I need to do this to refer to the right table. So, how do I use variables to insert the fieldnames which were set before the SQL query?

Comment: Without knowing too much more about the why or performance requirements, but recognizing your want to create a dynamic query, I would recommend looking into rewriting this with dynamic sql?

Comment: I never heard of dynamic sql. I'll have a look at it. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where and how you use that query you could use

**SQLCMD variables**

```
:setvar FKFIELD field_name

SELECT 
    ad.id 
    , ad.@fk_field
    , a1.@jnktn_field
FROM @tblname tbl LEFT JOIN @jnktn_tbl jnktn ON tbl.$(FKFIELD)=jnktn.field
WHERE ad.FK1 <> isnull(a1.ID,0)
```

**EXECUTE Statement**

```
EXEC('SELECT 
    ad.id 
    , ad.@fk_field
    , a1.@jnktn_field
FROM @tblname tbl LEFT JOIN @jnktn_tbl jnktn ON tbl.' + @fk_field +'=jnktn.field
WHERE ad.FK1 <> isnull(a1.ID,0)')
```

**Multiple JOIN clauses**

```
SELECT 
    ad.id 
    , ad.field
    , a1.field
FROM @tblname tbl 
LEFT JOIN @jnktn_tbl jnktn ON tbl.Field1=jnktn.field and @fk_field = 'fieldName1'
LEFT JOIN @jnktn_tbl jnktn ON tbl.Field2=jnktn.field and @fk_field = 'fieldName2'
LEFT JOIN @jnktn_tbl jnktn ON tbl.Field3=jnktn.field and @fk_field = 'fieldName3'
WHERE ad.FK1 <> isnull(a1.ID,0)
```

UPDATE: This last example should require a bit of effort to get the query right and might not work at all depending on your exact requirements. The idea is to join to all referenced tables and set all fields from these tables to `NULL` except for the table with the key specified in the variable.

Comment: I still have problems with this. SQLCMD doesn't work. I don't know if EXEC will work because that sql query will also have to set a few other variables (I haven't been so far yet). I don't get what your Multiple JOIN clauses example is doing there. Can you explain that briefly?

Comment: @wullxz I tried to explain the idea, please see the updated answer. EXEC approach (i.e. dynamic SQL) could work for pretty much anything, but is a pain to debug. SQLCMD works with SQLCMD.EXE and from Query Analyzer if you enable SQLCMD mode (see Query menu).

Comment: I used the execute statement because it's the easiest and most flexible solution.